# Problem with Spark heap size memory on cluster

Tags: java, apache-spark, memory-management, heap-memory

I am working on one project that is allocated on cluster. And recently, time to time, I started to get this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: System memory 5767168 must be at least 471859200. Please increase heap size using the --driver-memory option or spark.driver.memory in Spark configuration.
```

This app is deployed on cluster, should I then change executorMemory property?
And can I do that in application.properties file in my Maven project, there is spark.executorMemory already specified, which is set to 1024? 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide further information? Are you running Spark in local mode or in a cluster? If so, how much memory have you assigned to each node (master, driver and executor)?

Comment: @ÁlvaroValencia We are running Spark in a cluster. I can see that we assigned 1024(probably mb) for driver and the same amount for executor. I am not sure how much for the master. The strange thing is that we get above message from time to time, not constantly. If you have any suggestion, or more questions, please post.